# Setting undesired records rows value as NULL

Tags: mysql

When I run this update query in my server. Desired records are updating according to requirement. But all the other records reside in table1 set as NULL expect newly updated one. Any one there who can help on this. Thankyou in advance.

```
UPDATE MYDB1.`table1` t1
JOIN MYDB1.`table2` t2
    ON t2.id = t1.table2_fill_id
JOIN MYDB2.tbl3 t3
    ON t2.abc_id = t3.abc_id AND
       t2.date = t3.opn_date AND
       t2.flag IS TRUE
SET t1.value = t3.column15_value  
WHERE code = "ABCD";
```

Comment: Can you show sample data?  To which table does the `code` column belong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen column code belongs to table1.  If I run my update patch then the value of other records which do not have code "ABCD" becomes NULL. It is not issue for other column but only code column.

Comment: id table2_fill_id value code 

1001 A1          df        CC
1002 A2          ff       ABCD
1003 A3          fsf       DD,       here my CC and DD value of code  becomes NULL.

Comment: This should not be happening.  Are you sure the other values in `table1.code` did not already have `NULL` values?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. Something wired happening by  which I waste my whole day. And table1.code was not null before running this patch.

Comment: My guess is that you ran some other query which did this.

Answer (score 0):

first set output for last tables like

```
update table4 d join
(select a.id, b.name from table1 a, table2 b where a.id = b.id) table3 
   on d.id = table3.id and d.code = 'abcd' 
   set d.name = table3.name
```

this is just an example 
use your tables